# Cancel update on PreUpdateEventListener

Tags: nhibernate, event-listener

Is there a way to cancel the update action of an object on a PreUpdateEventListener, and mark it as non-dirty? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, this is easy after all:

> The event listeners themselves have a return value. What this return
>   value does is tell NHibernate whether to execute the actual
>   insert/update SQL queries. When you return false, it executes them.
>   When you return true, it does not. This way you can suppress the
>   actual persistence to the database.

Found it on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4035908/806975), and tested it on NH 3.0.

Still pending how to mark it as non-dirty, though.